# Hidden Markov Model Training

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model

I am reading more about sequence prediction tasks NLP specifically and am trying to fully understand HMMs and Viterbi. It seems that the latent structure for HMMs is just two matrices one for state transitions and the other for emissions which are based solely on corpus counts. Is this how HMM is trained just counts?

Comment: Two transition matrices?

Comment: I was reading this guide on HMMs and he describes transition matrices A and B that are for transitions and emissions.

Comment: perhaps only one of them was a *transition* matrix, and the other was an emission matrix

Comment: Yes that is correct, sorry I used incorrect vocabulary in my question and it has been fixed. Given this information I understand we can generate these matrices given a corpus by counting and then normalizing to produce probabilities but this is the initial probabilities how do we train HMM?

Comment: kind of hard to answer with what we ahve here, but typically, in the frequentist world, EM or MLE